# Haskell gloss: render Picture to Bitmap

Tags: haskell, gloss

I want to access the pixel data of what is being displayed to the window, but I have not had any luck finding such a function in gloss, nor by attempting to call OpenGL readPixels in a keyboard event callback. It looks like gloss renders a Picture to the window without exposing the rendered bitmap.

If this is hard to do in gloss, is there an alternative which has realtime high-level bitmap manipulation (translation, rotation, transparency)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `readPixels` can be used in this case. I found this snippet while digging through #haskell chat logs:

```
-- save a screenshot to a handle as binary PPM
snapshotWith :: (BS.ByteString -> IO b) -> Position -> Size -> IO b
snapshotWith f p0 vp@(Size vw vh) = do
  let fi q = fromIntegral q
      p6 = "P6\n" ++ show vw ++ " " ++ show vh ++ " 255\n"
  allocaBytes (fi (vw*vh*3)) $ \ptr -> do
    readPixels p0 vp $ PixelData RGB UnsignedByte ptr
    px <- BSI.create (fi $ vw * vh * 3) $ \d -> forM_ [0..vh-1] $ \y ->
      BSI.memcpy
        (d`plusPtr`fi(y*vw*3))
        (ptr`plusPtr`fi ((vh-1-y)*vw*3))
        (fi(vw*3))
    f $ BS.pack (map (toEnum . fromEnum) p6) `BS.append` px

writeSnapshot :: FilePath -> Position -> Size -> IO ()
writeSnapshot f = snapshotWith (BS.writeFile f)
```

From https://gitorious.org/maximus/mandulia/source/58695617c322b0b37ec72f9a0bd3eed8308bf700:src/Snapshot.hs

Answer (score 1):

Recently a new package [gloss-export](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-export) was released with the appropriate purpose:

> Export gloss pictures as PNG, Bitmap, TGA, TIFF, Gif

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same problem and couldn't find a good solution, so my answer probably won't be appropriate. My workaround was to use `bmp` package, deal with the `BMP` content manually (via `ByteString` manipulation), and then convert it to a glossy bitmap with `bitmapOfBMP`. For example, this was a function for blending a bitmap with a color:

```
recolor :: (Float, Float, Float) -> BMP -> BMP
recolor (rc, gc, bc) bmp@BMP {bmpRawImageData = raw} =
    bmp {bmpRawImageData = B.pack $ process $ B.unpack raw} where
    process (b:g:r:a:xs) = (mul b bc):(mul g gc):(mul r rc):a:process xs
    process xs = xs
    mul c cc = round $ cc * fromIntegral c
```

This was enough for me in that time, so I stopped finding a better solution. If you'll find something, please share.

Comment: I'm looking for the opposite conversion: Picture -> BMP